# Send messages between two VPN's in same solace Router

Tags: solace

I have two durable queues in two different VPN's , but both VPN's on same appliance. Client connects to VPN1 and post messages on durable queue. I want to send same messages to durable queue on VPN2. so the receiving client can consume the same messages. Is this possible using VPN bridges? 
Note: Client can connect only to Durable queue to send/receive messages.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible using VPN bridges?

Yes. You can create a local loopback VPN bridge between the two VPNs to move messages from one VPN to another.

Instructions to configure a VPN bridge can be found over at http://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing-Routers/Configuring-VPN-Bridges.htm